# sh: ./bc2influx: not found when entering in a stopped container

Tags: docker, go

I have an issue when running a docker container.

```
➜  bc_to_influx git:(master) ✗ docker run registry.gitlab.com/xxx/bc_to_influx:latest
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

When I debug, I enter in the stopped container:

```
docker commit 0db73216baaf  user/test_image 
docker run -ti --entrypoint=sh user/test_image
```

on `ls` command, I can only my executable:

```
/bc2influx # ls -al
total 20552
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun  6 10:32 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun  6 11:53 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      21034520 Jun  6 10:29 bc2influx
/bc2influx #
```

but when I try to execute, I get:

```
/bc2influx # ./bc2influx 
sh: ./bc2influx: not found
```

I can vi, cat the execute, but not execute it

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /bc2influx/
COPY ./release/bc2influx /bc2influx/
RUN ls -al /bc2influx/
CMD [ "./bc2influx" ]
```

I previously build my executable with:

```
go build -o ./release/bc2influx -v -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' ./...
```

Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: Looks like musl library issue try this build command `go build -ldflags="-s -w"` or disable cgo `CGO_ENABLED=0`

Comment: If I put CGO_ENABLE=0, I get: vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:18:10: undefined: SQLiteConn

Comment: it seems to have worked with -s -w ! Now I get another error message, will post it in another question after investigating. Please put it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `musl` library issue try this build command `go build -ldflags="-s -w"`.